# Pathauto alias produces inconsistent aliases

Tags: uri, path-aliases

I have a content type with its own Pathauto pattern `studios/[node:title]`. What could be the reason that the alias of the node entitled "Studio A" is `studios/studio`, whereas for "Studio B" (for the same language) - `studios/studio-b`. The latter being the desired shape of course.
I tried to resave the node, I tried to bulk delete aliases and re-generate them - all to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check settings in  `Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases` there is a *Strings to Remove* like this:

> a, an, as, at, before, but, by, for, from, is, in, into, like, of,
>   off, on, onto, per, since, than, the, this, that, to, up, via, with

thats why your **A** is removed i think.